# Pink Objects/Sub-Meshes (NOT MATERIALS)

Tags: unity, blender, 3d-meshes, unity-urp

Using URP. Any object I import into unity from blender (fbx), the sub-mesh that comes with it are pink. All the materials are fine, I can put the object in my scene with a material and it looks normal. But in the project view, there is two instances of any object, one that looks normal, and a sub-mesh that's pink. Because the meshes are pink, I'm not able to use them inside of the VFX graph as a particle mesh output. I've tried upgrading all materials multiple times, and making new blend files doesnt work either. Every single object does the same thing. Any insight would be appreciated.[image: Pink Sub-Meshes. Main object looks normal.]